# My wxpython program suddenly doesn't work for no reason

Tags: windows, wxpython

I made a program for school few weeks ego.. i have finished it yet.

for some reason, when i am trying to run the program now, it doesn't work, although it worked well in the last time a tried.

I am sure that i didn't change anything in the code, but there is always a chance that something has changed and i didn't payed attention..

I need to pass it to my teacher in these days and i have no idea what is wrong with the program.

I will glad to get some help here..

here is the code:

```
import wx
import winsound
import wx.grid as gridlib
from random import randint

OPTIONS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "DEL", 0, "SEND"]
# these are the events' IDs sent to a function when you click a button.
# the OPTIONS_ID is in the same order of OPTIONS.

OPTIONS_ID = [-31984,-31983,-31982,-31981,-31980,-31979, -31978, -31977, -31976, -31975, -31974, -31973, -31985]  # the built in wxpython IDs for the buttons


GAME_POSITION = (400, 100)
GAME_SIZE = [900, 600]

def RandomNum():
    count = 5
    while count > 4:
        num = randint(1000, 9999)
        digits = str(num)
        count = 0
        for digit in digits:
            for digit2 in digits:
                if digit == digit2:
                    count = count + 1
    return digits

class Frame(wx.Frame):  # class for all the frames in our game.
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size)
            self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
            self.fdf = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(275, 75), pos=(520, 20))
            self.count = 0
            self.turnsCounter = 0
            self.numbers = RandomNum()
            self.bulls = 0
            self.cows = 0
            self.counter_of_turns = 0
            self.check = False

            self.grid = gridlib.Grid(self.panel, pos = (85, 150), size=(323, 212))
            self.grid.CreateGrid(10, 3)
            sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            sizer.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
            sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.EXPAND)
            self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
            for i in range(10):
                for j in range(4):
                    self.grid.SetReadOnly(i, j)
            self.grid.SetColLabelValue(0, "guess")
            self.grid.SetColLabelValue(1, "cows")
            self.grid.SetColLabelValue(2, "bulls")


    def message_dialog(self, message, caption, style=wx.YES_NO, position=GAME_POSITION):
        if message != "":  # making sure not to execute a message if its empety
            message = wx.MessageDialog(None, message, caption, style, position)
            answer = message.ShowModal()
            if answer == wx.ID_YES:
                self.reset()
            else:
                self.Destroy()
        else:
            return -1
    # this function creates a textbox at a specific position with a specific size.
    def write(self, panel, txt, pos, size=20, font_family=wx.SWISS, font_style = wx.NORMAL,font_weight = wx.BOLD, underline = False, color=wx.WHITE):
        # create a textbox at a specific position with a specific size.
        your_txt = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, txt, pos)
        your_txt.SetFont(wx.Font(size,font_family,font_style,font_weight,underline))
        your_txt.SetForegroundColour(color)
    # same as above, just for a button.
    def create_button(self, panel, txt, position, width, height, color, disable):
        Size = wx.Size(width, height)
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, txt, position, Size)
        self.button.SetBackgroundColour(color)
        self.border = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.border.Add(self.button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt: self.OnButton(evt), self.button)
        if disable == True:
            self.button.Disable()

    def count_bulls(self, txtctrl, seria):
        for i in range(4):
            if seria[i] == txtctrl[i]:
                self.bulls += 1
        replacement = self.bulls
        self.bulls = 0
        return replacement

    def count_cows(self, txtctrl, seria):
        for i in range(4):
            if seria[i] != txtctrl[i] and seria[i] in txtctrl:
                self.cows += 1
        replacement = self.cows
        self.cows = 0
        return replacement

    def reset(self):
        self.fdf.Clear()
        self.grid.ClearGrid()
        self.count = 0
        self.turnsCounter = 0
        self.numbers = RandomNum()
        self.bulls = 0
        self.cows = 0
        self.counter_of_turns = 0
        self.check = False
        for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
            if child.GetLabel() != "SEND":
                child.Enable()
            else:
                child.Disable()
            if self.count == 0:
                if child.GetLabel() == "DEL" or child.GetLabel() == "0":
                    child.Disable()
    def OnButton(self, event):
        print repr(event.Id) + ","
        print self.numbers
        if event.Id in OPTIONS_ID:  # if indeed an option button was pressed
            exited = -1  # exited is 5100 if the user exited his dialog box
            # assigning the events to the button.
            for i in range(13):
                if event.Id != -31985 and event.Id != -31975 and event.Id != -31974 and event.Id != -31973 and event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[i]:
                    self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[i]))
                    self.count += 1
            if event.Id == -31974:
                self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[10]))
                self.count += 1
            if event.Id == -31985:
                self.reset()
            if event.Id == -31973:
                self.counter_of_turns += 1
                print self.numbers
                print self.fdf.GetValue()
                cows = self.count_cows(self.fdf.GetValue(), self.numbers)
                bulls = self.count_bulls(self.fdf.GetValue(), self.numbers)
                self.grid.SetCellValue(self.turnsCounter,0, self.fdf.GetValue())
                self.grid.SetCellValue(self.turnsCounter, 1, str(cows))
                self.grid.SetCellValue(self.turnsCounter, 2, str(bulls))
                self.fdf.Clear()
                self.count = 0
                if self.turnsCounter < 9:
                    self.turnsCounter += 1
                if bulls == 4:
                    self.check = True
                    winsound.PlaySound('The_Power_-_Snap_1_.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_LOOP)
                    self.message_dialog("Well done! you won this game..\n You won the game in %s turns .. \n Play again ? " % self.counter_of_turns , "You won!")
                    winsound.PlaySound(None, 0)
            if event.Id == -31975:
                if self.count > 0:
                    self.count -= 1
                self.fdf.Remove(self.fdf.GetLastPosition()-1, self.fdf.GetLastPosition())
            if self.count == 4:
                for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
                    if isinstance(child, wx.Button):
                        try:
                            int(child.GetLabel())
                        except ValueError:
                            if child.GetLabel() == "SEND":
                                child.Enable()
                        else:
                            child.Disable()
            elif self.check == False:
                for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
                    if child.GetLabel() != "SEND":
                        child.Enable()
                    else:
                        child.Disable()
                    if self.count == 0:
                        if child.GetLabel() == "DEL" or child.GetLabel() == "0":
                            child.Disable()
            #for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
                #if isinstance(child, wx.Button):
                    #if child.GetLabel() in self.fdf.GetValue():
                        #child.Disable()
            if self.counter_of_turns == 10 and self.check == False:
                self.message_dialog("YOU LOST :( \n THE NUMBERS WERE %s \n  PLAY AGAIN ?" % self.numbers,"Bad news ..")

class Game(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):  # upon game opening
        # I would like the options window to be the first window's parent
        # so I will first set up our options window:
        window = Frame(None, -1, "Good Luck!", GAME_POSITION, GAME_SIZE)
        first_panel = window.panel
        window.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        window.write(first_panel, "BULLS AND COWS!", (50, 50), size=(35))
        countX = 500
        countY = 100
        window.create_button(first_panel,"restart!", (50, 400), 100, 100, wx.WHITE, False)
        for option in OPTIONS:
            if str(option) == "SEND" or str(option) == "DEL":
                window.create_button(first_panel,str(option), (countX, countY), 100, 100, wx.GREEN, True)
            elif str(option) == "0":
                window.create_button(first_panel,str(option), (countX, countY), 100, 100, wx.WHITE, True)
            else:
                window.create_button(first_panel,str(option), (countX, countY), 100, 100, wx.WHITE, False)
            countX += 110
            if str(option) == "3" or str(option) == "6" or str(option) == "9":
                countY += 110
                countX = 500



        window.Show(True)
        return True


def main():
    MasterMind = Game()
    MasterMind.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

PLEASE NOTE:

I upgraded my windows to windows 10 few days ego, it means that it doesn't work since the upgrade if it means something. (sorry if the grammer of my english not so well, it is not my native language..).

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Works fine for me. Did you accidently update to wxPython Phoenix and/or Python3 while updating Windows?

Comment: I didn't update it to nothing..

it drows all the buttons and stuff, but they look empty (i see only the margin of them), and at the same time an error messageDialog jumps, saying that 'python.exe' has stopped working and windows search for solution (but doesn't find)..

Answer (score 0):

In my computer works fine (Python 2.7.11 and windows 7). If you import this class in another file, make sure if you call the main function.

Comment: I don't understand.. what should i do to make it works again? do you think it is related to the fact that i have just upgraded to windows 10?

Comment: I don't know, wxpython works normal on Windows 10. Look at the console maybe some error is raising.

Comment: it drows all the buttons and stuff, but they look empty (i see only the margin of them), and at the same time an error messageDialog jumps, saying that 'python.exe' has stopped working and windows search for solution (but doesn't find)..